# Audits Google Chrome - Controle e elementos devem ter rótulos

Tags: html, google-chrome

Rodei o Audits do Google Chrome e alarmou em acessibilidade que meus inputs não possuem rótulos, porém esotu utilizando placeholder, o que acham? Acredito que esse erro acusado não seja real, o que acham?

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" value="" placeholder="Nome"/>
<br />
<input name="email" type="email" id="email" size="30" value="" placeholder="Email"/>
<br />
<input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="30" maxlength="13" onKeyUp="javascript:somente_numero(this);" onkeypress="formatar_mascara(this,'## ####-#####')" placeholder="Telefone"/>
```